# Gulp watch error with gulp-pug

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I am trying to set up my gulp to watch for pug changes, but I get the following error, and I have no idea what that can be:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (19:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVar (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1034:28)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseVarStatement (/../node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:917:10)
```

My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const pug = require('gulp-pug');    

gulp.task('pug', () =>
  gulp.src('pug/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug({ pretty: false }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))    
);

gulp.task('watch', function (){
  gulp.watch('pug/*.pug', ['pug']);
});
```

Comment: Which is the line 141? Do you have that folder (and at least a pug file)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem could potentially be `.pipe(gulp.dest('.'))` you should specify an actual folder name. e.g. `.pipe(gulp.dest('folderName'))`  / 
 `.pipe(gulp.dest([__dirname])`

Additionally add a `return` statement to `gulp.src('pug/*.pug')`
so it looks like

`return gulp.src('pug/*.pug')` it's avoids errors with the inclusion of a `return` statement.

Can you edit your question to include your Pug file, please ?